# No default signer found when checking the balance of a wallet

Tags: solana-cli, solana-keygen

I'm trying to create a solana wallet using solana-keygen and then check it's balance With this line I create the wallet with the spesific outfile

```
C:\Users\Ali Berkin>solana-keygen new --force -o "C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json"
```

It generated the wallet successfully and outputted me this

```
Generating a new keypair

For added security, enter a BIP39 passphrase
NOTE! This passphrase improves security of the recovery seed phrase NOT the                                                                                                                                                  
keypair file itself, which is stored as insecure plain text
                                                                                                                                                              
BIP39 Passphrase (empty for none):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Wrote new keypair to C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json                                                                                               
================================================================================                                                                                  
pubkey: CgvYXNqdVLvNvByFXiSkFGfRC3QFR9SGZq17Bq1bRdht                                                                                                              
================================================================================
```

then I saved this keypair as my default keypair

```
C:\Users\Ali Berkin>solana config set --keypair "C:\Users\Ali 
Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json"                                                                  
Config File: C:\Users\Ali Berkin\.config\solana\cli\config.yml                                                                                                    
RPC URL: https://metaplex.devnet.rpcpool.com/                                                                                                                     
WebSocket URL: wss://metaplex.devnet.rpcpool.com/ (computed)                                                                                                      
Keypair Path: C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json                                                                                                      
Commitment: confirmed
```

Finally, when I tried to check my balance, it threw an error which looks like this

```
C:\Users\Ali Berkin>solana balance
Error: Dynamic program error: No default signer found, run "solana-keygen new -o 
C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json" to create a new one
```

I already created a keypair at C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json but error tells me to create one. Can someone help me with this?

Edit:
I'm sure that test json is at the right directory

```
C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana>dir                                                                                 
Volume in drive C has no label.                                                                                         
Volume Serial Number is 229F-F657                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Directory of C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana                                                                                                                                                                                              
30.07.2022  15:48    <DIR>          .                                                                                   
30.07.2022  15:48    <DIR>          ..                                                                                  
30.07.2022  15:35    <DIR>          airdrop_project                                                                     
30.07.2022  15:48               231 test.json
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you try doing an airdrop. `solana airdrop 1` -- what happens?

Comment: I got the same error: Dynamic program error: No default signer found

Comment: Hmm can you confirm that the file actually exists at `C:\Users\Ali Berkin\Documents\Solana\test.json `

Comment: Another thought is, could be due to the space in your username. Could you create a new keypair to the default path, and try the commands again.

Comment: yes sir, I edited the question you can check

Comment: I opened a new directory on C:\ and it seems to work now, I guess you are right. The space on my user name must've caused a problem, thank you sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the space in your username.

Consider choosing a path with no space or use the default path for the keypair file.